# How to add multiple generated folder in build path using maven plugin

Tags: java, jaxb, maven-plugin

[image: generated files]

I am trying to generate Java class from from multiple xsd and would like to add it in build path but only one package(i.e. xjc) is adding not all (xjc08 and xjc09)
below is pom.xml

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.14.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>schema-generate</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources</schemaDirectory>
                        <schemaIncludes>
                            <include>text.xsd</include>
                        </schemaIncludes>
                        <generatePackage>com.model</generatePackage>
                        <generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/xjc</generateDirectory>


                    </configuration>

                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>schema2-generate</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources</schemaDirectory>
                        <schemaIncludes>
                            <include>test1.xsd</include>
                        </schemaIncludes>
                        <generatePackage>com.model1</generatePackage>
                        <generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/xjc08</generateDirectory>

                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>schema3-generate</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources</schemaDirectory>
                        <schemaIncludes>
                            <include>Test2.xsd</include>
                        </schemaIncludes>
                        <generatePackage>com.model2</generatePackage>

     <generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated- 
     sources/xjc09</generateDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Please advise what needs to be done to add whole target folder in build path.

Answer (score 0):

Try after adding below the plugin in your pom.xml. Just specify your directory where your java class are getting generated.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>add-source</id>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>add-source</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <sources>
            <source>some directory</source>     
          </sources>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

OR

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>.</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
        <includes>
            <include>src/main/java/**/*.java</include>
            <include>src/main2/java/**/*.java</include>
        </includes>
        </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: thanks @mak , I have added this code even though it's not working. it's only adding one package under target/generate-sources/xjc . As per my configuration 3 package needs to be created under xjc

Comment: can you try with the second approach ? Because that works for me

Comment: Can we add target file in second approach.

Comment: I don't think we can add, Because while you run mvn install then only target folder is getting updated. I never try honestly. But why you need to do that, If you have multiple packages then you can add accordingly.

Comment: Yes, But i tried to add but only one package is added which not other two.